# Issue creating an angular filter function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to filter results using checkbox values.  I need to be able to filter by rating.  This is the code I have so far:

```
    <label ng-repeat="rating in ratings">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{rating.value}}" ng-model="rating.selected" ng-change="ratingFilter(hotel, rating)" ng-init="ratingFilter(hotel, rating, 'init')">
         {{rating.name}}
    </label>


 $scope.ratings = [
    { name:'One Star', value:1, selected: true}, 
    { name:'Two Stars', value:2, selected: true},
    { name:'Three Stars', value:3, selected: true},
    { name:'Four Stars', value:4, selected: true},
    { name:'Five Stars', value:5, selected: true}
 ]



         <div ng-repeat="hotel in (filteredHotels = (hotelResults | filter: resortFilter | filter: bbFilter | filter: priceFilter | filter: ratingFilter)) | startFrom:(currentPage - 1)*10 | limitTo:10 " class="hotel-results-container">
```

I'll need a `ratingFilter` function, something like this:

```
$scope.ratingFilter = function (hotel, rating, init) {

    return (hotel.Rating >=  $scope.hotelResults.Rating);
}
```

This doesn't work though.

I've created a `priceFilter` function and this works:

```
$scope.priceFilter = function (hotel) {
    return (hotel.Price > $scope.hotelResults.minPrice && hotel.Price < $scope.hotelResults.maxPrice);
}
```

Can anyone help me filter the results by rating?

Comment: You use 'hotelResults' as collection (ng-repeat) AND object ('$scope.hotelResults.minPrice') at the same time. What is it?

Comment: Perhaps this is part of the problem.  It looks like these data structures are basically the same.  All I'm trying to do is if the checkbox is checked return the data that has the checkbox value within it.  I've tried loads of things today and I'm maybe not understanding this fully to solve it.  Sorry I'm lost :(

Comment: this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wYfs4/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this sorted by rewriting the priceFilter and ratingFilter functions so they now look like this:

```
.filter('rangeFilter', function() {
   return function(hotelResults, price ) {

    var filtered = [];
    var priceMin = parseInt(price.min);
    var priceMax = parseInt(price.max);

    angular.forEach(hotelResults, function(hotel) {
      if((hotel.Price >= priceMin && hotel.Price <= priceMax)) {
        filtered.push(hotel);
      }
    });

    return filtered;
  };
})


.filter('ratingsFilter', function() {
  return function(hotelResults, ratings) {
    filteredResults = []
    angular.forEach(hotelResults, function(hotel) {
      angular.forEach(ratings, function(rating) {
        if (hotel.Rating === rating.value && rating.selected === true) {
          filteredResults.push(hotel)
        }
      })
    })
    return filteredResults;
  }
})
```

Ratings html looks like this:

```
<div class="filter--hotel__container quarter">
  <label ng-repeat="rating in ratings">
    <input name="rating" type="checkbox" ng-model="rating.selected" ng-checked="rating.selected"> {{rating.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Slider html for pricing looks like this:

```
<!-- Price range slider -->
<div data-range-slider data-min="hotelResults.minPrice" data-max="hotelResults.maxPrice" data-model-min="price.min" data-model-max="price.max" data-show-values="false"></div>

<!-- Minimum price -->
<div class="hotel-search__price-min">
  <span data-ng-bind="price.min|currency:'£'"></span>
</div>

<!-- Current selected price -->
<div class="hotel-search__price-max">
  <span data-ng-bind="price.max|currency:'£'"></span>
</div>
```

The ng-repeat code looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="hotel in (filteredHotels = (hotelResults | filter: searchFilter | filter: resortFilter | filter: bbFilter | rangeFilter:price | ratingsFilter:ratings )) | startFrom:(currentPage - 1)*10 | limitTo:10 " class="hotel-results-container">
```